# Please help me with Group Policy Object Editor

Tags: permissions, group-policy

I had these questions. I think i blew it but would like to know what the answer should be. I don't have any real world experience with Group Policy Objects

> 1. You have applied a group policy on the top level of a OU(San
>      Francisco). Under "San Francisco" there are two OUs. 1) "San Francisco
>      City" 2)"San Francisco Police". What do you do to stop the group
>      policy from applying to "San Francisco Police" Objects?
> 2. Consider the same OU structure as in the previous question. There are
>      100 users under the "San Francisco Police" OU. Your task is to apply a
>      group policy under "San Francisco Police" to a specific group of
>      users. How you accomplish this?
> 3. In Group Policy, what is Block inheritance and Enforcement.

I told the interviewers

1. Block Inheritance (i guessed. I was unable to give them step by step instructions on a follow up question)
2. No Idea
3. Not sure

Comment: This is Home work?

Comment: I had a job interview. I think I bombed it. Was looking for a little help. The job is for San Francisco